# Refresh jsf page when forwarding to itself

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm developing a JSF webapp with a PrimeFaces tree as it's navigation.
For example:

- Project 1

  - Customer 1
  - Customer 2
- Project 2

  - Customer 3
- etc

When the user clicks a node, the backing bean forwards to the appropriate page like this:

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "null", "/" + /*Page Name*/ + ".xhtml");`

This is not a problem when navigating from a project page to a customer page or the other way around. However, when I'm on a project page and try to navigate to another project page (say from Project 1 to Project 2), the page doesn't refresh (presumably because JSF assumes it's already on the correct page).

How can I force JSF to refresh the page when navigating to itself?

I don't want to use `faces-redirect=true` to keep the URL in the browser from changing.

Thanks!

Comment: What is "*refresh*" in this context? `Project 1` and `Project 2`, do they mean/represent two different/separate applications running on their own separate contexts (hereby you are interested in cross-context forwarding which in turn, may not be supported/permitted by all containers - a big caveat and should not be underestimated)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: Project 1 and 2 refer to the same page, but with different content. It's a page displaying the project's details, but when I'm on the page for project 1 and click on project 2, it doesn't refresh, so it still shows the info for project 1.

Comment: Just stop abusing POST for navigation and use GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an extra xhtml file that calls the navigation method on load. Now clicking a tree node redirects to that file and the navigation method then redirects to whichever page is appropriate for the selected node.

This approach isn't exactly programatically elegant, but it works and doesn't noticably slow down the application.